# findByParentIdDeletedIsFalse like query in Spring Boot MongoRepository

Tags: spring-boot, mongorepository

I know that, in MongoRepository, there are autogenerated queries like `findByParentId` and `findByDeletedIsFalse`. I want to get a result that both `ByParentId` and among them only the field `deleted = false` ones.

I did my research but not come across with such an example. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , it should be work as

Considering example where i want to find user who's having email with case insensitive and deleted property set as false

So only need to combine autogenerated queries with **AND** operator and pass email as parameter.

Like :

```
findByEmailIgnoreCaseAndDeletedFalse(String email)
```